# MySQL reorder row id by date

Tags: mysql, mariadb

SELECT time
FROM posts
ORDER BY time ASC;

This will order my posts for me in a list. I would like to reorder the table itself making sure that there are no missing table ids. Thus, if I delete column 2, I can reorder so that row 3 will become row 2.

How can I do this? Reorder a table by its date column so there is always an increment of 1, no non-existing rows.

Comment: That's not really what IDs are for. They are supposed to unique and not necessarily gapless.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't really know why you would need to do it, but if you do, here is just one of many ways, fairly independent of the engine or the server version.*

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t (`time`) VALUES ('13:00:00'),('08:00:00'),('02:00:00');
DELETE FROM t WHERE id = 2;
```

**Initial condition:**

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY `time`;
+----+----------+
| id | time     |
+----+----------+
|  3 | 02:00:00 |
|  1 | 13:00:00 |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Action:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr AFTER UPDATE ON t FOR EACH ROW SET @id:=@id+1;
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN new_id INT NOT NULL AFTER id;
SET @id=1;
UPDATE t SET new_id=@id ORDER BY time;
DROP TRIGGER tr;
```

**Result:**

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY `time`;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | new_id | time     |
+----+--------+----------+
|  3 |      1 | 02:00:00 |
|  1 |      2 | 13:00:00 |
+----+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Cleanup:**

Further you can do whatever is more suitable for your case (whatever is faster and less blocking, depending on other conditions). You can update the existing `id` column and then drop the extra one:

```
UPDATE t SET id=new_id;
ALTER TABLE t DROP new_id;

SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY `time`;
+----+----------+
| id | time     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 02:00:00 |
|  2 | 13:00:00 |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or you can drop the existing `id` column and promote `new_id` to the primary key.

**Comments:**

A natural variation of the same approach would be to wrap it into a stored procedure. It's basically the same, but requires a bit more text. The benefit of it is that you could keep the procedure for the next time you need it.

Assuming you have a unique index on `id`, a temporary column `new_id` is needed in a general case, because if you start updating `id` directly, you can get a unique key violation. It shouldn't happen if your `id` is already ordered properly, and you are only removing gaps.

Comment: People need this to keep using order by id instead of date